# how to make fmincon honor constraints at each step?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a nonlinear filter using fmincon in the MATLAB Optimization Toolboox, keeping the eigenvalues of the state equation matrix less than one. The documentation for fmincon using the 'sqp' algorithm says that it respects the constraints at all iterations, and yet at the very first iteration of my code it tries a point implying unstable eigenvalues. I can't run the filter at these parameter values, and so my code crashes.

Does the documentation really mean that 'AlwaysHonorConstraints' only applies to the inequality constraints passed in as vectors (lb and ub)? Is there any way to ensure that the non-linear constraints are satisfied at each step?

Here is the relevant piece of my code:

```
c = @(x) max(abs(eig(reshape(x(8:16), 3, 3)))) - 1;
ceq = @(x) [];                 
nonlcon = @(x) deal(c(x), ceq(x));

obj = @(x) -unscented_kalman1(x, fulldiv, crsp_allEverything);

fminconOptions = optimset('Display', 'iter-detailed', 'Algorithm', 'sqp', ...
 'TolX', errTol, 'UseParallel', 'always', 'AlwaysHonorConstraints', 'bounds');

maxX = fmincon(obj, x0, [], [], [], [], [], [], nonlcon, fminconOptions);
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "at the very first iteration of my code it tries a point implying unstable eigenvalues" do you mean the first iteration of `fmincon` using `x0`? Have you tried different starting values? What do you set `x0` to?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) indeed states that the `'AlwaysHonorConstraints'` option applies to the *bound* constraints only, so `lb` and `ub`. In other words, `fmincon` considers the entire domain `[lb  ub]` as the feasible region and ignores any and all linear and non-linear constraints.

Quite some time ago I wrote `optimize`, which is based on `fminsearch` and is available [on the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24298-optimize). Now, it's a long time ago, so I might misremember, but I remember implementing an option (`'superstrict'`) that avoids *any* evaluation of the objective function outside the feasible region, *including* linear and non-linear constraints. You might want to give that a try.

But, sticking to `fmincon`, a possible workaround is to modify `unscented_kalman1` such as to include penalties:

```
function unscented_kalman1(x, ...)

    %// evaluate constraint (yes, also here, unfortunately)
    c = @(x) max(abs(eig(reshape(x,2,2)))) - 1;
    penalties = c > 0;

    %// modify x by thresholding 
    if penalties          
        x = ... %// [MODIFY x SUCH THAT IT LIES INSIDE THE FEASIBLE REGION]
    end

    %// ... remainder of the function here

    %// then finally: 
    y = ... %// [THE OUTCOME OF THE FUNCTION];

    if penalties  
         y = y + c.^3;  %// ...or something similar
    end

end
```

This makes it possible to run your filter, but returning a *much* higher value for the objective function when the constraints are broken. This "forces" `fmincon` into the feasible region.

Take care though that the penalty function you use does not introduce discontinuities. Something like

```
 y = y + 1e8*c;
```

would not be suited, because if `y` is *just* inside the feasible region, the returned value is just `y`, but if it then *just* outside the region at the next iteration, it will suddenly jump up by *millions*. This is problematic, because SQP in `fmincon` uses first and second derivatives of `y`, which also turn to millions in the neighborhood of a discontinuity like that, screwing up the next iteration.